# Android. Which is better XML or Code to load images for 2 languages

Tags: android

I have an application that is suppose to be built in English and Arabic. so i have drawable-en and drawable-ar.

My question is, is it better to set the images in XML, because android will figure out which language is selected and to show the appropriate image. Or i do this through code and check for language and set its image. I don't want the application to crash with memory error etc.

Method 1: `android:background="@drawable/background2"`

Method 2:
//here some cache is put into work.

```
 ImageResourceHandler.RenderImageBackgroundForView(getResources(), findViewById(R.id.imageView), R.drawable.activitybackground);
```

//this is direct image set to backgroup

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.languageButton)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.langeng);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because android will figure out which language is selected and to
>   show the appropriate image

You solved your own question ;) this is the Android way of working.

The other way is also possible but less code is easier to maintain